# What is the correct usage of the Verb "abängsten" in German?

Tags: verb, separable-verb

Canoonet.eu has given a list of [phrasal verbs](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/Controller?service=inflectionRules&filter=VerbSeparable&inflectionClass=Trennbare%20Verben&entryClass=Cat%20V), but I cannot really find the correct usage of most of these verbs. What is the correct usage of *abängsten*?

Comment: Never heard that word, really. Was suspecting a typo until I saw dictionaries really seem to list it. Seems to be entirely out of fashion since at least 100 years ago. The construct seems to be similar to *abtrotzen* with "Angst" replacing "Trotz" - i.e. talk somebody into something by making him fear something

Comment: For some reason, I read *abhengsten*...

Answer (score 4):

#### [abängsten/abängstigen](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=ab%C3%A4ngstigen)

Both verbs were used synonymously in the past but *abängsten* is no longer used and *abängstigen* only rarely used in modern German.

Both were reflexively used similar to [*sich ängstigen*](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=%C3%A4ngstigen) but with the prefix *ab-* to further strengthen the meaning. An English translation for *sich abängstigen* could be

> to be overly frightened of sth., to be overly scared for so. (*coll.* to be uberscared)

Answer (score 1):

The word is archaic, so correct current usage is not to use it at all. Nevertheless you can find it [in a dictionary](http://dwds.de/?qu=ab%C3%A4ngsten) with the example

> Jettchen ängstigte sich um ihn Stunde um Stunde ab.

Comment: Apparently, there also seems to be a *jemandem etwas abängstigen* : F. Schiller, Geschichte des 30-jährigen Kriegs: "...Eilfertigkeit, mit der er die Ausführung dieser Entwürfe verfolgte, brachte ihn um die Geldsummen, welche er durch ein längeres Verweilen in Franken dem ohnmächtigen Bischof leicht hätte abängstigen können;"

Comment: Yes, Takkat put more effort into his (later) answer, but a downvote, really?

Comment: @tofro, yes I could have added references to DWB and Adelung, but I wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: Downvote and comment are not related... Not my downvote, and no, I don't understand it either.

Comment: @tofro, hätte ich auch nicht angenommen.